# Using promise with observable in ionic 2 applications

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-http

I am trying to call a web service in ionic 2 application but getting struck in between promise and observable.
This is my function which i am calling on click of a button-

```
getUserDetailsIfAccessTokenIsSuccess()


{
    this.remedyService.userGetDetail(this.loginDetailsObj.username).subscribe(
      data =>{
        console.log("userGetDetail Success="+JSON.stringify(data));
      },
      err =>{
        console.log("userGetDetail Success="+JSON.stringify(error));
        },
       () =>{
              console.log("Get Userdetails Completed");
      });
}
```

Now i am calling userGetDetail function in my service file.

```
userGetDetail(eid){
    var url = '/userGetDetail';
    var params = {
                'EID':eid
            };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
    var headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    this.storage.get('remedyAccessToken').then((value)=>{
        var token  = value.toString();
        console.log("TOKEN IN REMEDYSERVICES="+token);
        headers.append('Authorization', token);
        console.log("header value inside="+JSON.stringify(headers));
    })
    console.log("header value outside="+JSON.stringify(headers));
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.response = this.http.post(url,this.urlEncode(params),options).map(res => res.json());
    console.log("Response JSON="+JSON.stringify(this.response));
    return this.response;
}
```

Now the issue is that before Authorization is getting appended to header the flow is going to next line and web api is giving error.
Is there anyway i am can synchronise in such a way that after Authorization is appended then only service call should happens.
I tried putting the web api call inside then block but it makes the service calls as a promise.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct way to call an observer inside a promise and the return an observer will be like this-

```
return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('remedyAccessToken')).then((value)=>{
    var token  = value.toString();
    console.log("TOKEN IN REMEDYSERVICES="+token);
    headers.append('Authorization', token);
    console.log("header value inside="+JSON.stringify(headers));
    console.log("header value outside="+JSON.stringify(headers));
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   this.response = this.http.post(url,this.urlEncode(params),options).map(res => res.json());
   console.log("Response JSON="+JSON.stringify(this.response));
   return this.response.toPromise();
})
```

Comment: I do not see a ``get`` operator on ``Observable`` . http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html

Comment: updated to then method of promise...it was a mistake

Comment: There is an extra bracket in the solution. And mark an answer so that it would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the `api` inside the `storage.get` . This makes sure value is available when you make api call. Then convert the `api` call which is an `Observable` to promise with `toPromise()`. Now you can access the response as `Promise` . Here is an approximate workflow from your code.

```
this.storage.get('remedyAccessToken').then((value)=>{
    var token  = value.toString();
    console.log("TOKEN IN REMEDYSERVICES="+token);
    headers.append('Authorization', token);
    console.log("header value inside="+JSON.stringify(headers));
    console.log("header value outside="+JSON.stringify(headers));
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   this.response = this.http.post(url,this.urlEncode(params),options).map(res => res.json());
   console.log("Response JSON="+JSON.stringify(this.response));
   return this.response.toPromise();
})



this.remedyService.userGetDetail(this.loginDetailsObj.username).then(fn).catch(fn);
```

or if you like the output to be an `Observable` follow this approach.

```
Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('remedyAccessToken')).flatMap((value)=>{
        var token  = value.toString();
        console.log("TOKEN IN REMEDYSERVICES="+token);
        headers.append('Authorization', token);
        console.log("header value inside="+JSON.stringify(headers));
        console.log("header value outside="+JSON.stringify(headers));
       let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
       this.response = this.http.post(url,this.urlEncode(params),options).map(res => res.json());
       console.log("Response JSON="+JSON.stringify(this.response));
       return this.response
})
```

This approach achieve the result you want.

Comment: Hi Raj, is there anyway i can convert the return this.response to an observer?

Comment: HI Raj, i guess flatMap is not a property of promise<>,my storage is returning promise, so flatMap cant be used here.

Comment: sorry there was a bracket missing in my answer. I have updated it. ``flatMap`` acts on ``Observable``. You might have to import it.

``import 'rxjs/add/operator/flatMap'``.

Comment: Thank you, i got the solution. Thanks for the help and happy new year.

Comment: @RHUL Mark it as answer if it helped